# how to create sliding tab button in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-button

I follow a tutorial for creating a sliding tab or segment component using animation like below:

[image]

```
const SlidingTabBar = (props) => {

  const [active, setActive] = useState(0)
  const [xTabOne, setXTabOne] = useState(0)
  const [xTabTwo, setXTabTwo] = useState(0)
  const [transX, setTransX] = useState(new Animated.Value(0))

  const handleSlide = (type) => {
    Animated.spring(transX, {
      toValue: type,
      duration: 100
    }).start()
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
    <View style={styles.tabContainer}>
     <Animated.View style={styles.active, {transform: [{ translateX: transX}]}} />
     <TouchableOpacity onLayout={(e) => setXTabOne(e.nativeEvent.layout.x)} onPress={() => setActive(0), handleSlide(xTabOne)}><Text>tab one</Text></TouchableOpacity>
     <TouchableOpacity onLayout={(e) => setXTabTwo(e.nativeEvent.layout.x)} onPress={() => setActive(1), handleSlide(xTabTwo)}><Text>tab 2</Text></TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  tabContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'blue',
    width: 300,
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    position: 'relative',
  },
  active: {
    position: 'absolute',
    backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
    width: '50%',
    height: '100%',
    left: 0,
    top: 0
  }
})
```

but when I implement my transform on the View component my overlay disappear and break like this:

[image]

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple in starting I was also struggling in this but I sort it out

Note: code is for functional component

just do it take a View as button container and inside it take to button like this

```js
   <View style={styles.tabGroup}>
      <TouchableOpacity
          activeOpacity={0.6}
          underlayColor="#0000ff"
          onPress={()=> handleTab("tab1")}
          style={[styles.tabButton, tab.tab1 && styles.tabButtonActive]}

      >
         <Text style={[styles.tabButtonTitle, tab.tab1 && styles.tabButtonTitleActive]}>Tab btn1</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity
         activeOpacity={0.6}
         underlayColor="#0000ff"
         onPress={()=> handleTab("tab2")}
         tyle={[styles.tabButton, tab.tab2 && styles.tabButtonActive]}
      >
         <Text style={[styles.tabButtonTitle, tab.tab2 && styles.tabButtonTitleActive]}>Tab btn2</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
```

Add some styles to button and button group

```css
    tabGroup:{
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(11, 93, 30, 0.11)',
      borderRadius: 46,
      marginHorizontal: 20,
      justifyContent: 'space-between'
    },
    tabButton:{
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        borderRadius: 46,
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
        paddingVertical: 12,
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    tabButtonActive:{
        backgroundColor: '#0B5D1E',
        borderRadius: 46,
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
        paddingVertical: 12,
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    tabButtonTitle:{
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: 'normal',
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#000'
    },
    tabButtonTitleActive:{
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: 'normal',
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#fff'
    }
```

Then define function and state on the top of

```js
    const [tab, setTab] = useState({
        tab1: false,
        tab2: true
    });

    const handleTab = (swap) =>{
       if(swap==="tab1"){
            setTab({
               tab1: true,
               tab2: false
            })
       }
       else{
        setTab({
            tab1: false,
            tab2: true
     })
       }
    }
```